# Filtering GeoJSON on a feature property value

Tags: javascript, json, geojson

I'm trying to filter, or better 'split' a GeoJSON object by a value in a feature property and create n new geoJSON storing them into an array.

here is the GeoJSON I'm working on: http://www.brainsengineering.com/1.json

I have to split it by 'Level' property, by creating as many new GeoJSONs variables as the number of levels present in the original GeoJSON
In the above example file, there are 4 levels.

Here is the code that is partially working:

```
//geoData is the variable holding the GeoJSON
var featureCount = geoData.features.length;
var maxLevel;
var geoByLevel = []; 

//retrieve the maximum number of levels
for (var i = 0; i < featureCount; i++) {
    if (geoData.features[i].properties.Level > maxLevel) {
        maxLevel = geoData.features[i].properties.Level;
    }
}

//Split geoData content into the geoByLevel array by level
for (var i = 1; i <= maxLevel; i++) {
    geoByLevel[i-1] = geoData.features.filter(function (el) {
            return el.properties.Level == i
    });
}
```

This code partially works because I correctly get the features split by levels into the array, but they are not valid GeoJSON as I loose the first objects

{"**type**":"FeatureCollection","**hc-transform**": {"default": {"crs": "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"}}, "**features**":...

is there a way to recreate the objects keeping also these elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've currently solved by concatenating the missing strings to the stringified object and then parsing back the whole new string to a JSON object:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= maxLevel; i++) {
    geoByLevel[i - 1] = JSON.parse('{"type":"FeatureCollection","hc-transform": {"default": {"crs": "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"}},"features":' + 
        JSON.stringify(geoData.features.filter(function (el) {
        return el.properties.Level == i
    })) + '}');
}
```

Not so elegant but it works. Someone knows a more elegant/efficient way to achieve the same result?

Comment: I need to know how to do this in python